# ionic directive remove first option from select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, ionic-framework, directive

I'm trying to make a directive which should remove the first option of a select.

I'm using this html to generate the select box:

```
 <select remove-whitespace ng-model="user.encryption">                                      
      <option ng-repeat="r in selectButtons" title="{{r.text}}" ng-selected="$first" value="{{r.value}}">{{r.text}}</option>                            
 </select>
```

This part of code is in my controller to populate the select box in the view:

```
    $scope.selectButtons = [
        {text: "Clear-Text", value: "no_encryption"},
        {text: "MD5", value: "md5_encryption"},
        {text: "SHA1", value: "sha1_encryption"},
    ];
```

I'm using this as my directive:

```
.directive("removeWhitespace", function () {
    return{
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {            
            console.log(element.context); 
        }
    }
});
```

When i do a console.log(element.context); the following context appears in my browser console:

[image: Screenshot]
Yet I can't seem to remove the option with value "? undefined:undefined ?"

Answer (score 0):

It seems i've found a solution to my own question:

To properly populate a select box you need to use ng-options instead of ng-repeat.

I ended up using the following:

```
     <select ng-model="selectButton"
      ng-options="r.text for r in selectButtons">                                
     </select>
```

This will populate a selectbox without whitespace. And the directive is not needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The first element (? udefined:undefined ?)is there because the current value of the ng-model does not match any of the options. It will go away on its own if you do something like this in your controller:

```
$scope.user.encryption="no_encryption"
```

To answer the question fully, here is a simple directive that removes the first option of a select, though I would advise against using anything like it because it would be better to use ng-options possibly combined with a filter

```
angular.module('app').directive('removeFirst',function(){
  return{
    link:function(scope,element) {
      element.find('option')[0].remove();
    },
  }
})
```